# Display version name

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-manifest

I want to display the versionName ( number) located in the android manifest on my spalsh screen. I found some example codes but they are not working. This seems like a simple task but it does not display for me

text view from splash xml:

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ver_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:text=" " />
```

display method:

```
    private void displayVersionName() {
    String versionName = "";
    PackageInfo packageInfo;
    try {
        packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
        versionName = "ver:" + packageInfo.versionName;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ver_name);
    tv.setText(versionName);
  }
```

Comment: @njzk2 I have main in the settings screen so one can quickly check

Comment: post stack trace ? do you have logs ? when do you call this method ?

Comment: Have you tried to Log the version number at any point? `Log.i("displayVersionName", "Version: " + versionName);`. I can't see anything wrong with the code you're *showing* here.

Comment: BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME duuuuuuuuuuuuuuude!!!!!!

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps `NameNotFoundException` gets thrown? Or perhaps something happens when you are displaying the version string?

Anyway, I have exactly the same as you and it does work for me. You can verify with the below code what getVersionInfo returns, and only then try to display it

```
public String getVersionInfo() {
        String strVersion = "Version:";

        PackageInfo packageInfo;
        try {
            packageInfo = getApplicationContext()
                .getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo(
                    getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), 
                    0
                );
            strVersion += packageInfo.versionName;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            strVersion += "Unknown";
        }

        return strVersion;
    }
```

Comment: you are really not supposed to receive an exception here, given that the package name is the name of the currently running package, which, obviously, is installed (and hence can be found)

Comment: @Alex(@njzk2) LOL - in the ADT I actually get reprimanded for not catching the exception if left out - but there's a missing semi-colon after "Unknown". Still +1.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ver_name);
 tv.setText("version : " + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);
```

And import the `BuildConfig` of the package where you want to have the versionName :

```
import com.yourpackage.BuildConfig;
```

Comment: yeah just the BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME , don't understand the efforts in the other answers

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as to get Your application version name using code

```
    private void displayVersionName() {
    String verName = "";
    try {
        verName = "ver:" + Current_Activity.this.getPackageManager().
                            "YOUR_APPLICATION_PACKAGE_NAME", 0).versionName;  
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ver_name);
    tv.setText(verName);
  }
```